# Swift Mullti level Filtering

Tags: arrays, json, swift, filter

```
    {
    "productId" : "prod830028",
    "deviceFeatures" : [
        "SIM Type:Nano",
        "Battery:3,174mAh",
        "Front Camera:7MP",
        "Rear Camera:12MP + 12MP",
        "OS:iOS 12",
        "Processor:A12 Bionic chip with next-generation Neural Engine",
        "Display:6.5 inches, OLED"
    ],

    "productOverView": "Meet the iPhone X - the device that’s so smart that it responds to a tap, your voice, and even a glance. Elegantly designed with a large 14.73 cm (5.8) Super Retina screen and a durable front-and-back glass.",
    "specifications":[
        {
            "key": "Color",
            "value": "Space Grey"
        },
        {
            "key": "Internal Memory",
            "value": "64 GB"
        },
        {
            "key": "Operating System",
            "value": "iOS 11.1.1"
        },
        {
            "key": "Primary Camera",
            "value": "12 MP"
        },
        {
            "key": "RAM",
            "value": "5.8 inch"
        },
        {
            "key": "Screen Size",
            "value": "15"
        },
        {
            "key": "Expandable Memory",
            "value": "No"
        },
        {
            "key": "Camera Feature",
            "value": "Geo-tagging, simultaneous 4K video and 8MP image recording, touch focus, face/smile detection, HDR (photo/panorama)"
        }
    ],
    "preorderable" : false,
    "responseMsg" : "SUCCESS",
    "skuDetails" : [
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "4461.45",
            "pointsWithVat" : "393900",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "375143",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9F",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "3751.43",
            "priceWithVat" : "3939.0015",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "362.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052451"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "185.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052468"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "244.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052593"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202391",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202391",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "4249.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "424900",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-SpaceGray-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#8C8C8C",
                    "value" : "Space Gray",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "64GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "446145",
            "demandId" : "3060416"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "4461.45",
            "pointsWithVat" : "316575",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "301500",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9I",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "3015.0",
            "priceWithVat" : "3165.75",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "362.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052402"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "185.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052634"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "244.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052559"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202404",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202404",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "4249.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "424900",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-Silver-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#C0C0C0",
                    "value" : "Silver",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "64GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "446145",
            "demandId" : "3060419"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "4461.45",
            "pointsWithVat" : "393900",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "375143",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000GAL",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "3751.43",
            "priceWithVat" : "3939.0015",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "185.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052605"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "362.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052640"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "244.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052646"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202419",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202419",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "4249.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "424900",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-Gold-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#D4AF37",
                    "value" : "Gold",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "64GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "446145",
            "demandId" : "3060494"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "5065.2",
            "pointsWithVat" : "445500",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "424286",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9E",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "4242.86",
            "priceWithVat" : "4455.003",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "210.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052406"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "277.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052372"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "411.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052571"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202438",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202438",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "4824.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "482400",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-SpaceGray-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#8C8C8C",
                    "value" : "Space Gray",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "256GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "506520",
            "demandId" : "3060415"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "5065.2",
            "pointsWithVat" : "445500",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "424286",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9Y",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "4242.86",
            "priceWithVat" : "4455.003",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "210.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052650"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "411.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052353"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "277.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052520"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202453",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202453",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "4824.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "482400",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-Silver-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#C0C0C0",
                    "value" : "Silver",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "256GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "506520",
            "demandId" : "3060445"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "5065.2",
            "pointsWithVat" : "445500",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "424286",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9B",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "4242.86",
            "priceWithVat" : "4455.003",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "411.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052561"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "277.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052510"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "210.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052448"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202469",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202469",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "4824.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "482400",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-Gold-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#D4AF37",
                    "value" : "Gold",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "506520",
            "demandId" : "3060412"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "5884.2",
            "pointsWithVat" : "525500",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "500476",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000GA0",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "5004.76",
            "priceWithVat" : "5254.9980000000005",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "336.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052601"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "499.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052569"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "255.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052361"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202486",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202486",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "5604.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "560400",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-SpaceGray-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#8C8C8C",
                    "value" : "Space Gray",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "512GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "588420",
            "demandId" : "3060451"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "5884.2",
            "pointsWithVat" : "525500",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "500476",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9O",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "5004.76",
            "priceWithVat" : "5254.9980000000005",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "255.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052466"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "499.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052319"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "336.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052334"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202505",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202505",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "5604.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "560400",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-Silver-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#C0C0C0",
                    "value" : "Silver",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Storage",
                    "value" : "512GB",
                    "displayText" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Memory",
                    "value" : "4GB RAM",
                    "displayText" : "Memory"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "588420",
            "demandId" : "3060427"
        },
        {
            "oldPriceWithVat" : "5884.2",
            "pointsWithVat" : "525500",
            "pointsWithoutVat" : "500476",
            "ratePlanCode" : "RPDLAPAPPEQ000000G9S",
            "priceWithouthVat" : "5004.76",
            "priceWithVat" : "5254.9980000000005",
            "devicePaymentOptions" : [
                {
                    "price" : "499.0",
                    "duration" : "12",
                    "demandId" : "3052340"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "336.0",
                    "duration" : "18",
                    "demandId" : "3052613"
                },
                {
                    "price" : "255.0",
                    "duration" : "24",
                    "demandId" : "3052324"
                }
            ],
            "payWithPointAvailable" : false,
            "skuId" : "bgSku3820202524",
            "vatPercentage" : "5",
            "sicCode" : "3820202524",
            "oldPriceWithoutVat" : "5604.0",
            "oldPricePointsWithoutVat" : "560400",
            "cashOnDeliveryAvailable" : true,
            "images" : [
                "https:\/\/www.etisalat.ae\/en\/system\/wst\/assets\/img\/devices\/AP-iPhoneXSMax\/AP-iPhoneXsMax-Gold-PureAngles-500.jpg"
            ],
            "skuCoreProperties" : [
                {
                    "colorCode" : "#D4AF37",
                    "value" : "Gold",
                    "key" : "Colour",
                    "displayText" : "Colour"
                }
            ],
            "oldPricePointsWithVat" : "588420",
            "demandId" : "3060430"
        }
    ],
    "brand" : "Apple",
    "responseCode" : "0000000",
    "name" : "iPhone XS Max"
}
```

I have above json. what i want is to use filter to get skudetails of object for only those whose color is gold and storage is 64 gb. can it be achievable through filter? As for first level filtering its working fine for me like this :

```
 if let skuDetailArray = self.deviceSKUsAndDetailsResponse?.skuDetails
 let demandId =  skuDetailArray.first(where: { $0.demandId == "3060416" })
```

but i could not able to parse data for above conditions, and if its not possible through than can it be possible through predicate, or any other method than please let me know.

**

- UPDATE: showing class for these models

**

```
class SWGetDeviceSKUsAndDetailsResponseModel : SWBaseResponseModel {

    let brand : String?
    let deviceFeatures : [String]?
    let name : String?
    let preorderable : Bool?
    let productId : String?
    let productOverView : String?
    let skuDetails : [SWSkuDetail]?
    let specifications : [SWSpecification]?

}
```

class SWSkuDetail : Codable {

```
let cashOnDeliveryAvailable : Bool?
let demandId : String?
let devicePaymentOptions : [SWDevicePaymentOption]?
let images : [String]?
let oldPricePointsWithVat : String?
let oldPricePointsWithoutVat : String?
let oldPriceWithVat : String?
let oldPriceWithoutVat : String?
let payWithPointAvailable : Bool?
let pointsWithVat : String?
let pointsWithoutVat : String?
let priceWithVat : String?
let priceWithouthVat : String?
let ratePlanCode : String?
let sicCode : String?
let skuCoreProperties : [SWSkuCoreProperty]?
let skuId : String?
let vatPercentage : String?
```

}

class SWSkuCoreProperty : Codable {

```
let colorCode : String?
let displayText : String?
let key : String?
let value : String?

}
```

Comment: If you want help with filtering an array of a struct hierarchy  you should post the code for the struct hierarchy rather than the json data.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson added class for models for more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return any `SWSkuDetail` that has the Color = Gold and Storage = 64 GB.

The filter function first filters out the elements with the given keys and then check that it has gotten 2 hits and that both values exists in those two.

```
let keyColor = "Colour"
let keyStorage = "Storage"

let filtered = skuDetailArray.filter { detail in
    guard let props = detail.skuCoreProperties else { return false }
    let array = props.filter { $0.key == keyColor || $0.key == keyStorage }.map {$0.value}
    return array.count == 2 && array.contains("Gold") && array.contains("64GB")
}
```

Comment: wow that was great its work like charm. i need to know one thing more : let array = props.filter { $0.key == keyColor || $0.key == keyStorage }.map {$0.value} what if with addition of color and storage, i have key value pair of other core properties too, like memory, dual sim  e.t.c .  is there any better way instead of using hardcoded keyColor and key storage.

Comment: means instead of specifying any keys can i get  swskudetail with only basis of values ?? @Joakim Danielson

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi you could turn it into a function that takes the search parameters as an argument. Maybe in the form of a dictionary

Comment: yes but how can i do this ? please help me out on this also ..

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi I see in your second comment that you now want to filter only on values and not on key/value pairs so it feels like it is a completely new question. You can skip the filter on keys then and directly use `map` and then `contains` on the values. Perhaps have the values in an array and check each in a loop